# Ajax return array shows [object Object],[object Object] in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

Within Jquery I am creating two arrays, one embedded in the other, like so....

```
arrayOne = [{name:'a',value:1}, {name:'b',value:2}]
var arrayTwo = [{name:'foo',value:'blah'},{name:'arrayOne',value:arrayOne}];
```

I am then putting this though Ajax and extracting the variable via PHP on the other side. The results of a print_r($arrayTwo) are as follows...

```
Array([foo] => blah [arrayOne] => [object Object],[object Object])
```

I can see no way of extracting the contents of arrayOne, which is a pity because I really need them!  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong in Jquery or what I need to do in PHP to make the embedded array accessible.

Many thanks as always

---

Edit to add my Ajax code....

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:'actions.php',
  data:arrayTwo,
  datatype:'json',
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){

}
```

})

Comment: Seems like you are not serializing your data properly before you send it. `[object Object]` is the default string representation of a JavaScript object: `console.log({}.toString())`. Post the code you use to send the data.

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: print_r($arrayTwo['arrayOne']) just returns [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: JQuery Version 2.1.1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is that jQuery's `$.ajax` (or rather `$.param`) method treats an array of objects in a special way. jQuery will use `name` as the parameter name and the *string* representation of `value` as value:

```
> $.param([{name: 'foo', value: 42}, {name: 'bar', value: 21}])
"foo=42&bar=21"
```

But the string representation of `arrayOne` is the useless stuff you are seeing on the server:

```
> [{name:'a',value:1}, {name:'b',value:2}].toString()
"[object Object],[object Object]"
```

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) actually points out the caveats when passing an array / object:

> If the object passed is in an Array, it must be an array of objects in the format returned by `.serializeArray()`
>
> ```
> [
>   { name: "first", value: "Rick" },
>   { name: "last", value: "Astley" },
>   { name: "job", value: "Rock Star" }
> ]
> ```
>
> **Note**: Because some frameworks have limited ability to parse serialized arrays, developers should exercise caution when passing an `obj` argument that contains objects or arrays nested within another array.
>
> **Note**: Because there is no universally agreed-upon specification for param strings, it is not possible to encode complex data structures using this method in a manner that works ideally across all languages supporting such input. Use JSON format as an alternative for encoding complex data instead.

---

Since you have a complex data structure, you should probably use JSON to encode your data:

```
data: {data: JSON.stringify(arrayTwo)},
```

and on the server you simply decode it with

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
```

`$data` will have the exact same structure as `arrayTwo`.

But in case you want to actually have parameters with names `foo` and `arrayOne`, then you only need to serialize the the value of `arrayOne`:

```
data:  [
  {name:'foo',value:'blah'},
  {name:'arrayOne',value: JSON.stringify(arrayOne)}
],
```

and in PHP:

```
$arrayOne = json_decode($_POST['arrayOne'], true);
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the clear and accurate explanation. Works like a dream. Thank you very much.