# How to add multidimensional array to serialized POST data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So, I am trying to POST form data to my API... and I wanted to add an array (multidimensional) to the post data, but i can't seem to figure it out.

Here's what i got so far:

```
let move_type = $("#move_type").text();
let loc_id = $("#loc_id").val()
// check a few vars first


let postvars;
postvars = $('#myForm input').serializeArray();
postvars.push({name: 'loc_id', value: loc_id}); //uncomment if you need to add vars in the postvars
postvars.push({name: 'move_type', value: move_type}); //uncomment if you need to add vars in the postvars


//loop through product ques
let prods_r = [];
$(".que_item").each(function(index){
    let prod_id = $(this).find(".prod_id").text();
    let title = $(this).find(".title").text();
    let qty = $(this).find(".qty").val();
    if(qty<1) {
        showAlert("Please supply qty on all items in que. " + title);
        return false;
    }
    prods_r[prod_id] = [];
    prods_r[prod_id]["title"] = title;
    prods_r[prod_id]["qty"] = qty;


})

postvars.push(prods_r);
```

When submitting this I get the variable for prods_r as "undefined" with no value.

I've also tried the following line to no avail

```
postvars.push({name: `prods_r`, value:prods_r });
```

I'm definitely missing something here ey?

Answer (score 0):

You need to push all values to outer array else all values will get lost and it will return you empty array.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  let move_type = $("#move_type").text();
  let loc_id = $("#loc_id").val()
  let postvars;
  postvars = $('#myForm input').serializeArray();
  postvars.push({
    name: 'loc_id',
    value: loc_id
  }); 
  postvars.push({
    name: 'move_type',
    value: move_type
  });
  var dataa = new Array() //declare  this
  $(".que_item").each(function(index) {
    let prod_id = $(this).find(".prod_id").text();
    let title = $(this).find(".title").text();
    let qty = $(this).find(".qty").val();
    if (qty < 1) {
      showAlert("Please supply qty on all items in que. " + title);
      return false;
    }
    var prods_r = {}//create obj
    //add value to it..
    prods_r[prod_id] = {
      "title": title,
      "qty": qty
    }
    dataa.push(prods_r) //push in main array
  })

  postvars.push({
    name: "prods_r",
    value: dataa //passs it here 
  });

  console.log(postvars)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input tye="text" name="name" value="abc">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<div class="que_item">
  <span class="prod_id">1</span>
  <span class="title">Abcd</span>
  <input tye="text" name="ded" class="qty" value="34">
</div>
<div class="que_item">
  <span class="prod_id">2</span>
  <span class="title">Abcd2</span>
  <input tye="text" name="ded" class="qty" value="55">
</div>
```

Comment: tnx, tried this, but php receives it as  "[object Object]" https://i.imgur.com/H98R6Ms.jpeg

Comment: Did you tried like this  `JSON.stringify(dataa)` here `value: JSON.stringify(dataa)` ? Also , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33788635/ajax-return-array-shows-object-object-object-object-in-php) are some suggestion you can try.

Comment: yes, i could see JSON.stringify working and i could just json decode that on php side, but my goal is to pass it to server side "as array" as would be if it was extracted from form (ie. multi-select, file uploads, etc) 

sending to server as JSON string is not the goal. :(

Comment: So, your output should like this `value :[[],[],[]]` i.e : array of array ?

Comment: YES, here's what the server should receive it as (prod_r2, and not prod_r): https://i.imgur.com/08lnF0A.jpg

Comment: Still not sure as you need key-value pair so you need to push them in json-object normal array will not give key-value pair  .Anyways , check if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/m54vprdj/) work for you.